# Testnet Node Error - [cardano-:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Error:211493]

Tags: cardano-node, testnet

Currently running a test node and when it gets synced this error happens. So far I deleted the db/ folder and ran cardano-node again. Everything was going well but when it syncs this happened again. Node was running fine and observability looks good. Has anyone run into this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Cardano CLI Version: 1.29.0

Node Specs:
OS: Debian
Disk-Size: 50GB (Utilization under 50%)
CPU: 4vCPUs (At peak was at 63% Utilization)
Memory: 16GB (under 10%)

[image: Error Log Image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your node(s) to version 1.30.1. I am pretty sure doing so will resolve your issue.
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases

Comment: Ended up having to upgrade to 1.31.0-rc1. Sucks for anyone who didn't build from src and instead just downloaded the binary from IOHK. Fortunately I had built from source so it wasn't a big deal. Do you know where we go to see the release cadence? So we can update nodes preemptively?

Comment: So a couple of ways to stay up to date with this. IOG has a discord channel with an SP announcements channel : [link](https://discord.gg/cvEYF9r8) Then they also will make updates on the cardano_updates twitter: [link](https://twitter.com/cardano_updates)